# "One of your code blocks includes unescaped HTML." JS console security warning

Tags: xss, html

I operate a blog using Google's Blogger platform about programming. I use highlight.js for syntax highlighting, and now on my posts I see the console warning: `One of your code blocks includes unescaped HTML. This is a potentially serious security risk.` I read somewhere that this has to do with cross-site scripting (XSS) but I have no idea how to solve this issue. Here is an example of a code block in my post's HTML:

```
<pre>
    <code style="text-align: left;">
        button.addEventListener('click', () =&gt; {
            console.log('Button got clicked.');
        });
    </code>
</pre>
```

Note that while I typed this and other code blocks into the HTML editor inside of Blogger, I simply typed the `>` character and the editor changed it to `&gt;` (>) on saving. There are many examples of this within my posts. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you either link to the page in question, or post more of the code blocks? I don't think the one you posted is the one that caused the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the CDATA tag:

```
<pre>
    <code style="text-align: left;">
        <![CDATA[
            button.addEventListener('click', () =&gt; {
                console.log('Button got clicked.');
            });
        ]]>
    </code>
</pre>
```

The warning is telling you that your code includes unescaped HTML, which can be a security risk.

To fix this, you need to escape the HTML before it is rendered. One way to do this is to use a helper function from the `handlebars` package. This will escape the HTML for you. Alternatively, you may use the escape function from the `lodash` package. One of these approaches should fix the warning.